# Why is program not executed even though it is in my path?

Tags: command-line, bash

I am trying to run a program in `/usr/local/bin/` called `runserver`.

`/usr/local/bin` is in $PATH...

`echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

I am referencing the right program...

`which runserver
/usr/local/bin/runserver`

Yet when I try to execute `runserver` I get error that bash is trying to execute runserver in /usr/bin

`runserver
bash: /usr/bin/runserver: No such file or directory`

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/usr/local/bin/runserver`?

Comment: I stripped it down to something really simple... `cd /www`

Comment: Does the binary have the executable bit set (`chmod +x file`, I believe you otherwise get a permission denied error but I'm not sure)? Also, are you running a 64-bit OS and trying to execute a 32-bit binary? In this case you should install the 32-bit libraries (`apt-get install ia32-libs`).

Comment: What do you get when you specifically run `/usr/local/bin/runserver`?

Comment: Executive bits are set. It is a small bash script.

Comment: I get whatever the script is set to do. Originally it was supposed to launch a django dev server and that worked if I referenced it specifically. I thought there might be something in the script itself that was throwing it off, so I stripped it down but the same thing is still happening.

Comment: I really doubt what you have in the file, this is really strange, can you post it, please? And yes, while commenting use `@display_name` to notify the user you are replying to.

Comment: Can you just rehash your shell? `hash -r` for bash.

Comment: Show the output of the commands `type runserver` and `which runserver`. You probably have an alias, a shell function, a stale hash  or you are calling `/usr/bin/runserver` from the script itself. And as @Jobin says, post your script...

Comment: @choroba That was the problem. I had no idea there was this mechanism. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. If you make it an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your shell probably remembers an old file that doesn't exist anymore. Try rehashing:

```
hash -r
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the program executable? Try to do this first:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/runserver
```

Comment: There is no file in `/usr/bin/runserver`. The file is located in `/usr/local/bin/runserver`.